# Extjs Disabled Panel's Opacity

Tags: javascript, css, extjs4.1, opacity

I have a popup window which on creation disables the whole panel behind it. On the panel I have used `disabledCls: 'my-disabled-panel'` and in the css file

```
.my-disabled-panel .x-mask{
     opacity: 0 !important;
    -moz-opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

As opacity is 0, so it is supposed to disable the whole panel without giving the user any idea about the mask but in actuall there are still some components whose opacity changes.
Below images will make it more clear

[image]

[image]

It can be clearly seen that the opacity of three buttons in the top right corner has changed.

Comment: Is that component align to that panel? i mean is that sub items of panel?

Comment: are you talking about the buttons? These butons are placed inside a container whose layout is hbox and the popup window is aligned to the textfield with 'tl-bl?'.